# Do I need to encrypt MySQL server password?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database, encryption

I have a feeling this is a really basic question that everyone knows but I havnt used PHP in a while so I just want to make sure.

Im trying to create a webpage that will allow users to post comments. Since I need to store the comments im using a MySQL database, so I need to put the server information and my login credentials to allow my page to send form data to the database in the php code. Do I need to encrypt this information? And if I do how would I do that? I know how to encrypt something that a user inputs, but Im not sure how I would encrypt something that needs to remain in the code.

Comment: You're asking three different questions, but more than likely, the answer is no to all of them

Comment: MySQL is not SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can put the user and password in your PHP code.

It is possible, though rare, for a web server to reveal the PHP code to a user browsing the site. The Apache configuration should automatically *run* PHP code instead of displaying it, but I have seen some sites break their Apache configuration and accidentally reveal code.

An Apache config file, for example, needs a line like `AddHandler php5-script .php`. If the config file is edited, and someone makes a mistake, this php script handler could be disabled, and voilà, PHP code is treated just like a text file, and becomes visible to anyone.

So the better practice is to put your MySQL credentials in a file outside your html document root. Then any PHP script that needs it can use `include()` to read the file that contains the credentials. A PHP script can read files outside the document root, but any HTTP request cannot.

Another solution is to use the php.ini file. There are directives to set a default MySQL user & password. But you can configure only one set of credentials this way.

```
[mysqli]
mysqli.default_host = localhost
mysqli.default_user = scott
mysqli.default_pw = tiger
```

MySQL 5.6 has introduced encrypted storage of passwords, and a tool to edit the file where they are stored. But so far, this is really only useful for MySQL client tools, not PHP applications. Perhaps someday this feature will be integrated with the PHP native driver. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-config-editor.html

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, if your web server is secure, the client is not able to browse through your php files and code. Php is a server side language, which means that the client side (browser) does not see it. The browser sees client-side files, such as html files. This means that they do not have any way to obtain the file that has your login information inside of it, so there is no real need to encrypt it.

With that being said, you should make sure to use proper standards and make sure that your web server is secure, otherwise it could allow for a risk.

Answer (score -4):

PHP doesn't show on the front end. It's not html and does not show up in your browser. So no.

just browse this site: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: It does if the server isn't configured properly and spits out the db password

Comment: What are you talking about. How does that even happen. PHP is run ON the server, not IN your browser. So please enlighten me how you think this could happen

Comment: If the db username and password is stored in the document root and for whatever reason the server is not configured properly, it CAN show the raw code, pssword included

Comment: in that case you need another hosting party. Trust me on this, it never happens unless they are at the bottom of the hosting pool. And even then... So my answer remains no.

Comment: It isn't ISP's fault if you misconfigure the server yourself...

Comment: I have seen it happen. An Apache config file, for example, needs a line like `AddHandler php5-script .php`. If the config file is edited, and someone makes a mistake, this handler could be disabled and voila, PHP code is treated just like a text file, and becomes visible to anyone.

Comment: I'm not saying it's likely, I'm saying it's a possibility. Since the OP asked it the password is secure, I figured I'd mention it. Your answer is correct, but there are still security issues that need to be addressed. It's not so much the quality of the host, it's simply an accident that can happen when configuring something on the server.

Comment: then you should get your hosting somewhere else. Cause if you make that mistake that is the least of your problems cause your server is vulnerable in probably many other ways.

Comment: never link to w3schools please, its dangerously bad