# Is this a secure way of connecting to an SQL server?

Tags: php, mysql, database, security

Suppose I have a .php script on my server which interacts with a MySQL server. 
Part of it is:

```
function sqlQuery($queryString) {
    ...
    $mysqli = new mysqli("theHost:some-port", 
                         "DB_allowed_username", 
                         "password123", "dbName");
    ...
}
```

This script is solely server-side, and something like `DevTools` or `view-source://web.address` will not show the source code.

However, it is really important that nobody is able to see this source code because it bears my username and password for one of the privileged users of the database. Is there some other way someone could discover these details, and if so, how do I hide them more securely?

Note:- currently I have an SSL certificate but it is not guaranteed that I will have it indefinitely.

Comment: PHP is a server side language. All code gets executed on the server and won't be sent to the client. The only way someone could see the source code is if they have access to the server and can read the source files that way. I would argue that you then would have much bigger problems though.

Comment: _"I have an SLS certificate but it is not guaranteed that I will have it indefinitely."_ - Why not? If you care about security (which you should), then you should definitely always use SSL.

Comment: @M.Eriksson Thanks for your feedback. Firstly, I didn't spot that typo *SLS*; and while I see no reason currently for abandoning ssl, I may eventually (due to some unexpected circumstance) do so. After all, I have to take as many possibilities as I can into account

Comment: I don't see any reason you would even need to abandoning SSL (specially now a days when you can get certificates for free using Let's Encrypt). Sounds like you're preparing for a non-issue case, here. Either way, SSL is only for encrypting the data between the client and the server, while no one can see your PHP code unless they have access to the server (as it's never sent to the client at all).

Comment: Such info can splash to the web in the event of server misconfigurations. Best to store such info away from the web root's hands.

Comment: Most of the time its good practice to not have the SQL server accessible from outside localhost, so even if the credentials leak no significant damage can be done.

Comment: @nobody is there a way to configure that in the mySql server (using phpMyAdmin)?

Comment: @AlphaHowl https://stackoverflow.com/a/13208652/10264972

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browsers can see the PHP code only if your http server becomes misconfigured. I have seen this happen for example on Apache if the PHP handler directives are removed from the httpd.conf file. Then the code in `.php` files is delivered to browsers as-is.

A good way to protect your password against that (rare) possibility is to store the password in a config file that is read by your PHP code, and put the config file outside the Apache document root directory.

Comment: See also my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/24315768/20860